# Auto Complete jquery adding search icon

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete, and want to add Search icon in auto search input box, and when they start searching want to display search jpg. Can you anyone throw their suggestions on this.

Comment: you want to display an image inside a text box which also happens to have autocomplete attached to it? Or you want to display the image on the autocomplete list? And is it one image or two different ones you want to display? Your question is not very clear.

Comment: Im guessing a "search" icon in default state, and a "searching" img for when autocompleting. Both for the input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can observe a keyup event of your textbox. Try this:

```
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    }).keyup(function () {
        if (this.value !== '') {
            $(this).addClass('close');   
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('close');   
        }
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/5AASU/

Comment: this example doesn't work in Chrome in 2015, at least for me